# Finding the equation of a tangent line to a point on a surface.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We've been given a surface equation, we've found the gradient at the point, the direction at that point.

$$T(x,y)=-4x^2-2xy-5x-y^2-2y$$

The point where $T=3$.

I know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point in question..

We're now asked to find the equation of the tangent line.

There's no mention of anything in the books we've been given and the tutors don't really answer questions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Could I differentiate the whole thing at that point, and then use the equation in terms of a single y and x value?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question? I also think there is a typo, you write $T(x,t)$ but the right-hand side depends on $x,y$.

Comment: You could do a lot of things but they are unlikely to lead to the right answer until you understand the problem. You start by taking about a surface, and want to find “the” tangent line to it at a point. But a surface can have infinitely many lines tangent to it at a point. Is there missing information? Or could you be studying particular level curve instead of the graph?

Comment: There is a level we're told to use. I know that using the level turns it into a 2d shape instead of the 3d surface, but all the ways I know to find a tangent need an equation, and I've not been shown how to get that. I understand the concept, but the tangents aren't mentioned in The learning material.

Comment: This is the equation as I was give it.

Comment: Do you mean tangent to an isocurve ? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: This is why I'm confused. They haven't mentioned them at all so I don't know what's needed....grrrr.

Comment: I don’t see how you can “know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point [at which $T=3$]” when there is no such point. This function attains a maximum of $7/4$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for finding the equation of a tangent plane in a situation of 2 variables is;
$$z=f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b)$$
Where $f_x,f_y$ are the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

If the point considered is $(x_0,y_0)$, and the gradient vector is $(g_{x_0},g_{y_0})$, the line is

$$g_{x_0}(x-x_0)+g_{y_0}(y-y_0)=0.$$

---

If all you have is the gradient angle, use $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.